# Linq group by with multiple columns

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

net core projects. I am trying to retrieve unique rows for example, my table looks like below

```
Country_id  Country Reegion
----------  ------- -------
1           Germany Europe
2           UK      Europe
3           UK      Europe
```

In result, I am trying to get like this.

```
Country_id  Country   Reegion
----------  -------   -------
    1       Germany   Europe
    2       UK        Europe
```

In the above example, Countryid with value 2 and 3 has same value UK so I want to retrieve only one row. I tried using below code

```
var listOfGeographies = await GeographyRepository.GetAsync(x=>x.IsActive == true).ConfigureAwait(false);
var listOfUniqueGeographies = listOfGeographies.GroupBy(x => x.Country).Select(y => y.First());
IEnumerable<GeographyEntity> result = from o in listOfUniqueGeographies
                                      select new GeographyEntity
                                      {
                                          Id = o.CountryId,
                                          Country = o.Country,
                                          Region = o.Region,
                                          SubRegion = o.SubRegion
                                      };
```

Above code will return all the rows without grouping. May I know any changes I have to do in above linq query. Can someone help me on this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: why you are using x.CountryId  in GroupBy Clause when u want to only group by country?

Comment: You would like to have a distinct set of `Country` and `Region` combination and thus using those as the group key would work in your favour.

Comment: You can use `Min` in query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you need grouping on `Country` name as it is repeating in the data but with different id (which is strange) in that case you need to group and select the first one :

```
var result1 = myRepoOutput.GroupBy(x => x.Country)
                          .Select(b => b.First());
```

Comment: This works fine. Thanks. I have updated my code above. Just thinking is there any way we can combine the code

Comment: @Niranjangodbole what you mean ?

Comment: I added above code but thinking can we include group by clause in last statement?